# Creating bill using Acumatica SOAP results in error "System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null"

Tags: acumatica

Hello and thank you for reading!

I am trying to create a Bill using SOAP. To specify particular non-stock items, I extended endpoint and included field InventoryID-InventoryID into the BillDetail object. Then I updated WSDL file. Export Bills now works fine. But creation fails, with no info on the field.

Here is the code:

```
            string lcSQL, lcErrMsg, lcStage = "Start";

            AcmtIntegrator.AcumaticaWSDL.DefaultSoapClient soapClient = null;
            soapClient = new AcmtIntegrator.AcumaticaWSDL.DefaultSoapClient(clsACMT.CreateBinding(clsGlobals.gcAcmtURL),
            clsACMT.CreateEndpoint(clsGlobals.gcAcmtURL, clsGlobals.gcAcmtEndPoint, clsGlobals.gcAcmtVersion));

            string lcBranch, lcLocationID;
            lcBranch = mdlGU.GetSystemOption("ACMTEXTRACT", "CreditMemo", "Branch", "YOGIFON");
            lcLocationID = mdlGU.GetSystemOption("ACMTEXTRACT", "CreditMemo", "LocationID", "");

            // Bill Level:
            lcBranch = "SOFT";
            string docType = "Bill";
            string lcVendorCd = "EP00000001";
            string lcVendorRef = "VendorRef - 2";
            decimal lnBillAmt = 1000;
            string lcDocTxnDate = "20201005", lcDocDueDate = "20201104"; 
            string lcCashAccount = "102000SOFT";
            string lcBillDesc = "bill Desc 2";
            string lcRefNo = "RefNo";
            string lcTerms = "30D";
            string lcPostPeriod = "102020";


            int lnLineCount = 0;
            lcSQL = "select count(*) from tblCBInputCMItemLine where CMHdrID = " + Convert.ToString(1);
            lnLineCount = mdlGU.GetSQLScalar(lcSQL, 0);
            lnLineCount = 1;

            // Bill Line
            decimal lnLineExtAmt = 1000, lnUnitCost = 0, lnLineQty = 0;
            string lcLinePOOrderNbr = "", lcLinePOOrderType = "", lcLineDesc = "Line Desc", lcLineTranDesc = "Tran Desc";
            string lcLineAccount, lcLineSubAccount, lcUoM, lcLineItemInvID, lcLineProject = "", lcLineProjectTask = "";
            string lcItemAcmtGuid = "61594ca1-0d6b-e411-a445-e06995c86014";

            //

            BillDetail[] loBillDetails;
            loBillDetails = new BillDetail[lnLineCount];

            lcSQL = "select AcmtInventoryID from stdAcmtNonStockItem where AcmtGuid = '" + Convert.ToString(lcItemAcmtGuid) + "'";
            lcLineItemInvID = mdlGU.GetSQLScalar(lcSQL, "");
            lcSQL = "select ItemDesc from stdAcmtNonStockItem where AcmtGuid = '" + lcItemAcmtGuid + "'";
            lcLineDesc = mdlGU.GetSQLScalar(lcSQL, "");
            lcSQL = "select ExpenseAccount from stdAcmtNonStockItem where AcmtGuid = '" + lcItemAcmtGuid + "'";
            lcLineAccount = mdlGU.GetSQLScalar(lcSQL, "215000");
            lcSQL = "select ExpenseSubAccount from stdAcmtNonStockItem where AcmtGuid = '" + lcItemAcmtGuid + "'";
            lcLineSubAccount = mdlGU.GetSQLScalar(lcSQL, "");
            lcSQL = "select BaseUnit from stdAcmtNonStockItem where AcmtGuid = '" + lcItemAcmtGuid + "'";
            lcUoM = mdlGU.GetSQLScalar(lcSQL, "");

            loBillDetails[0] = new BillDetail
            {
                Branch = new StringValue { Value = lcBranch },
                Amount = new DecimalValue { Value = lnLineExtAmt },
                ExtendedCost = new DecimalValue { Value = lnLineExtAmt },
                UnitCost = new DecimalValue { Value = lnUnitCost },
                Qty = new DecimalValue { Value = lnLineQty },
                TransactionDescription = new StringValue { Value = lcLineTranDesc },
                Description = new StringValue { Value = lcLineDesc },
                POOrderNbr = new StringValue { Value = lcLinePOOrderNbr },
                POOrderType = new StringValue { Value = lcLinePOOrderType },
                Account = new StringValue { Value = lcLineAccount },
                Subaccount = new StringValue { Value = lcLineSubAccount },
                // InventoryID = new StringValue { Value = lcLineItemInvID },
                UOM = new StringValue { Value = lcUoM },
                //Project = new StringValue { Value = lcLineProject },
                //ProjectTask = new StringValue { Value = lcLineProjectTask }
        };

            Bill loBill = new Bill
            {
                ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.OnlySpecified,
                // Type = new StringValue { Value = docType },
                // ReferenceNbr = new StringReturn { Value = lcRefNo },
                Type = new StringValue (),
                ReferenceNbr = new StringReturn (),
                Status = new StringReturn(),
                Vendor = new StringValue { Value = lcVendorCd },
                VendorRef = new StringValue { Value = lcVendorRef },
                PostPeriod = new StringValue { Value = lcPostPeriod },
                Terms = new StringValue { Value = lcTerms },
                Hold = new BooleanValue { Value = false },
                Amount = new DecimalValue { Value = lnBillAmt },
                Balance = new DecimalValue { Value = lnBillAmt },
                CashAccount = new StringValue { Value = lcCashAccount },
                Description = new StringValue { Value = lcBillDesc },
                ApprovedForPayment = new BooleanValue { Value = true },
                BranchID = new StringValue { Value = lcBranch },
                Details = loBillDetails, 
            };

            // LocationID is optional
            if (lcLocationID != "")
            {
                loBill.LocationID = new StringValue { Value = lcLocationID };
            }

            if (lcDocTxnDate != "")
            {
                loBill.Date = new DateTimeValue
                {
                    Value = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(mdlGU.MyLeft(lcDocTxnDate, 4)),
                    Convert.ToInt32(lcDocTxnDate.Substring(4, 2)),
                    Convert.ToInt32(lcDocTxnDate.Substring(6, 2)))
                };

                loBill.DueDate = new DateTimeValue
                {
                    Value = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(mdlGU.MyLeft(lcDocDueDate, 4)),
                    Convert.ToInt32(lcDocDueDate.Substring(4, 2)),
                    Convert.ToInt32(lcDocDueDate.Substring(6, 2)))
                };

            };




            //Create a Bill 
            Bill newBill = new Bill();
            try
            {
                newBill = (Bill)soapClient.Put(loBill);
                //lcTxnID = newInvoice.ID.ToString();
                //lnPaidAmtCurr = newInvoice.Amount.Value.Value * lnAmtMultiplier;
                //lcDocRefNumber = newInvoice.ReferenceNbr.Value;
                // User to be "and CMNumberCurr = ''" Not sure why.
                // lcSQL = String.Format("Update tblCBInputCMHdr set ProcessingStatusID = 5, CMNumberCurr = '{0}', DocRefNumber = '{0}', TxnID = '{2}', PaidAmtCurr = {3} where CMHdrId = {1} and CMNumberCurr = ''", lcRefNumber, lnCMHdrID, lcTxnID, lnPaidAmtCurr);
                //lcSQL = String.Format("Update tblCBInputCMHdr set ProcessingStatusID = 5, CMNumberCurr = '{0}', DocRefNumber = '{4}', TxnID = '{2}', PaidAmtCurr = {3} where CMHdrId = {1}", lcRefNumber, lnCMHdrID, lcTxnID, lnPaidAmtCurr, lcDocRefNumber);
                //mdlGU.SqlClientExecuteSQL(lcSQL, "MakeCreditMemo", lcSQL, lcErrMsg);
                //mdlGU.WriteAppLog("Make CM", "HeaderID = " + Convert.ToString(lnCMHdrID), "Making CM Lines", false);
                //mdlGU.WriteAppLog("Make CreditMemo", "HeaderID = " + Convert.ToString(lnCMHdrID), "Set Status in tblCBInputCMHdr", false);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lcErrMsg = ex.Message.Replace("'", "").Substring(0, 900);
            }
```

The full error message says: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.\nParameter name: model\n   at Microsoft.Data.Edm.EdmUtil.CheckArgumentNull[T](T value, String parameterName)\n   at Microsoft.Data.Edm.ExtensionMethods.EntityContainers(IEdmModel model)\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Edm.Helpers.GetEntityType(IEdmModel model, String objectName)\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityReaderBase.ReadEntity(String expectedEntityType)\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityReaderBase.ReadEntity(XmlReader reader, String localname, String expectedNamespace, String expectedEntityType)\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapMessageTransformerBase.BindParameters(XmlReader requestReader, MethodInfo methodInfo, Tuple`2[] parameterInfos)\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.Post(ISoapSystemContract systemContract, XmlReader requestReader, String serviceNamespace, String internalNamespace, MethodInfo method, Fun"
Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' in mscorlib.dll

I am working with local version of Acumatica 2019 and training Tenant MyStore. I am logging in as Admin.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Alexander

Comment: The same error happens when creating Bill even on Default endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The login was missing.

```
soapClient.Login(clsGlobals.gcAcmtUserName, clsGlobals.gcAcmtPwd, clsGlobals.gcAcmtCompany, clsGlobals.gcAcmtBranch, null);
```